# How to get version of R8 that is being used by the Android Gradle Plugin?

Tags: android, android-r8

How can I find out which version of R8 is being used by the Android Gradle Plugin for let's say 4.0.1?

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This can be done by writing `println(com.android.tools.r8.Version.getVersionString())` anywhere in your Gradle script and executing any Gradle Task or just calling the Gradle Wrapper.

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
  }
}

println(com.android.tools.r8.Version.getVersionString())
```

Output:

```bash
$ ./gradlew

2.0.88 (build 19b089a1d5a73df8f00a27fda8b29b49782c621c from go/r8bot (luci-r8-ci-archive-0-z0tz))
```

This can also be added as a task to your Gradle script to not have it executed to configuration time:

```
tasks.register("r8Version") {
    doLast {
        println(com.android.tools.r8.Version.getVersionString())
    }
}
```

Running the `:app:r8Version` task:

```bash
$ ./gradlew :app:r8Version

> Task :app:r8Version
8.2.47 (build 62baf24ba2b71f4e5bc04c7f01930bc5d47b02be from go/r8bot (luci-r8-custom-ci-archive-0-19z6))
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to pass `--info` to the Gradle build.

Running `./gradlew --info app:assembleRelease` (AGP 4.1.1) includes the following info:

```
R8 is a new Android code shrinker. If you experience any issues, please file a bug at
https://issuetracker.google.com, using 'Shrinker (R8)' as component name. You can
disable R8 by updating gradle.properties with 'android.enableR8=false'.
Current version is: 2.1.75 (build 7c61a6224c35283ccaad7e85c848e3a71a716763 from go/r8bot (luci-r8-custom-ci-xenial-6-i8ri)).
```

However that will only be displayed if R8 is actually invoked.

Comment: Update 2024: This doesn't work. You can't find the version there anymore.

Comment: You should take a look at the first answer instead. I just updated it with the `:app:r8Version` task.